# Dynamically Created Excel From a Excel Template not writing Data Properly -SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, msbi

I need to create a `SSIS` Package which will run daily and export a table's data into a directory. The `Exported excel` have a predefined format. So I have used a  template excel. (`Excel` File with `Column Headers` only)

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Created a `variable` Filename  with holds the location and name of the `excel` to be generated 
   (based on current date value)
2. Added a `File System` Task in Control flow. Give Source as `Template Excel` and Destination as the `Filename` variable.
3. Added a `Dataflow` Task in control flow and connect it with File System Task.
4. In `Dataflow` Task, added a `OLE-DB source` and configure it with the `source table` (the table data needs to be copied into the `excel` )
5. Added a `Excel Connection manager` and changed `Excel File path` property to `filename` variable.
6. Added a `Excel Destination` and configure it with `Excel Connection manager.`
7. set `Delayed validation` true in `Data flow` task and Executed the package.

Control Flow:

[image]

Data Flow:

[image]

The Package is running successfully and the `excel` file also get generated in the desired directory. But the `excel` file skips around 19000 rows copying data after that . why it is happening?

Can any one help me to solve the issue.

Thanks for the help

Comment: How many sheets are there in the excel file?

Comment: one sheet. sheet 1

Comment: it is possible that the file is already formatted , and that lines are down at the bottom ? often excel jumps or add lines ... excuse me if I ask this , but we must also consider strange events...

Comment: @alex thanks mate for open my eyes!!! the data was copied afer 19842 th row! But I wonder how to write data from 2 row onwards

Comment: I have header and around 18000 blank rows. then the content. I think I should look into my template excel file for any corruptions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116658/discussion-between-alex-and-bmsqldev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the file is already formatted , and that lines are down at the bottom...often excel jumps or add lines if you do not delete the lines already used even if empty...we must also consider strange events!