# Actions mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss in excel destination using ssis

Tags: ssis

I am trying to extract the data from SQL table with datetime as datatype to excel sheet and I need the data in excel sheet as mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss. Please let me know the solution since I am getting text format in excel column as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss instead of mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss format.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46751638/5496498

Comment: Generally as long as it's date type, you should be good.   Don't worry about how it's displayed visually, as that's up to the end user and excel defaults.   If you want full control over the excel displayed formatting, you can also try sending to a [blank pre-formatted template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38240425).   Just double check that it's actually blank.

Answer (score 1):

Take a drived column component and convert the date as expected like following example:
[image]

This how you can convert the date:

```
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("mm",GETDATE()),2) + "/" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("dd",GETDATE()),2) + "/" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("yy",GETDATE()) + "  " + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("hour", GETDATE()) + ":" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("minute", GETDATE())+ ":" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("second", GETDATE())
```

Comment: Hi Khairul, I tried and able to extract the data in mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss format but the thing is the column in excel is getting treated as text format instead I am looking for date format since this file gets picked up by reporting tool where it picks only date format from the excel.